# draw custom shape and fill color upon specified value in php ci

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to draw a shape which looks like [a tank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apvGO.png). And and want to fill that tank with color depending upon some value. Just like battery of mobile. project in codeigniter. I have tried by using canvas, but color is filing complete box.
Can somebody help?

Comment: canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 150;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.lineTo(0,100);
ctx.lineTo(0,0);
ctx.fill();

Comment: in such shape, i want to fill color half of shape depending upon value @Nagesh Katke

Comment: No one gonna help you such way. Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: actually i dont have the cordinates for that shape. if i get the cordinates please help ow to fill it with color depending upon value? @Nagesh Katke